# How to upload a audio file using PHP?

Tags: php, html

I  wanted to upload a audio file using html and php .It always returns the error message(Invalid file).please kindly help me.
I am follow this url-
https://forums.digitalpoint.com/threads/mp3-file-upload-in-php.1174500/;

http://p2p.wrox.com/php-how/53040-how-upload-mp3-file-using-php.html

This is the code I am using-

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="sound_action.php" method="POST">
    <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE"/>
    Choose a file to upload: <input name="file" type="file" /><br />
    <input type="submit" value="Upload File" />
</form>

<?php
    if ((($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "audio/mp3")
    || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "audio/mp4")
    || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "audio/wav"))
    && ($_FILES["file"]["size"] < 1000000))
    {
        if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0)
        {
            echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br />";
        }
        else
        {
            echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["file"]["name"] . "<br />";
            echo "Type: " . $_FILES["file"]["type"] . "<br />";
            echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["file"]["size"] / 1024) . " Kb<br />";
            echo "Temp file: " . $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"] . "<br />";

            if (file_exists("upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]))
            {
                echo $_FILES["file"]["name"] . " already exists. ";
            }
            else
            {
                move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], "upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
                echo "Stored in: " . "upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"];
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        echo "Invalid file";
    }
?>
```

Comment: Have you tried echoing `$_FILES["file"]["type"]` to see if it matches?

Comment: How is a wrong file size classed as `Invalid file`, bad tut. check for `$_FILES["file"]["error"]` first, then size, then type

Comment: Worth nothing that $_FILES["file"]["type"] is not secure as it is actually provided by the client, not the actual file.

Comment: @LozCherone Invalid simply means Not Valid, it is down to the implementer to determine what is or is not valid...

Comment: @SecretSquirrel Its was the user I was thinking about. ;p

Comment: Thanks for the answer;there is no result when I echoing  $_FILES["file"]["type"].

Comment: @DKBHOI now check `$_FILES["file"]["error"]` then look up the manual

Comment: @DKBHOI add `print_r($_FILES["file"])` after `echo "Invalid file";` and check what data it holds.

Comment: @jogesh_pi Thanks for the answer;it holds- Array ( [name] => PK-02.MP3 [type] => [tmp_name] => [error] => 1 [size] => 0 )

Comment: @DKBHOI it's not getting the file type that you are trying to validate.

Comment: @jogesh_pi how to validate it,please give me little bit description

Comment: @LozCherone if you have any tutorial please give me the  links,so I learnt from that links

Comment: @DKBHOI take a look on the answer..

Comment: @jogesh_pi it return a Warning: Wrong parameter count for strrchr()

Answer (score 2):

The mime type of mp3 is `audio/mpeg` for mp4 you have to use `video/mp4` and wave is `audio/x-wav` or `audio/wav`.

Also you should increase the file size, because this argument is given in bytes and 1000000 is less than 1mb. Maybe you have also to increase the upload file size in php.ini

Answer (score 0):

There is an alternate way to validate a file, But it is a basic way to check the file validation not sure if file holds the correct type of not.

```
$valid_extension = array('.mp3', '.mp4', '.wav');
$file_extension = strtolower( strrchr( $_FILES["file"]["name"], "." ) );

if( in_array( $file_extension, $valid_extension ) && 
    $_FILES["file"]["size"] < 1000000 ){
    // Rest Logic Here
}
else
{
    print_r( $_FILES );
}
```

### Note:

This is a basic file validation.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing an if clause  :

```
if(isset($_POST['name_submit_button']))
{
   //Whole Logic of program
}
```